# After updating my Windows10, I cannot run Windows in my dual boot (Ubuntu/Windows) system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub, windows-update

I have a dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu PC. Yesterday I updated my Windows 10, but after that when I want to run my PC, grub comes, but I only can go to Ubuntu: every time I select Windows, it restarts and loads back to the same grub page.

I tried some time to shut down my laptop with  its button. but did not work. My grub page loads, but I can't go to Windows after updating.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please change the boot order at UEFI to boot Windows directly.

**Let Windows install any pending updates it has to install and then shutdown Windows.**

Now you can change the boot order back to Ubuntu (Grub) and both Ubuntu and Windows entries should work.

If for some reason the symptom is the same when booting Windows directly then the first thing you need to understand is that Grub can only boot working Windows (actually chainload to a working Windows bootloader), that your Windows isn't working as it show and should be corrected with Windows tools from a Windows installation media. This has nothing to do with Grub or Ubuntu.

PS - Don't forget to disable Fast Startup again in Windows. Feature updates tend to re-enable this feature.